# Setting image to a listView error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

App adds a user to `SQLite database`then retrieves all users found in the database to a `ListView` .

I want to check user's sex and then set him a logo .

using `logcat` gives this :

```
09-06 05:17:24.295: D/sexlogo(25590): sexlogo >>>android.widget.ImageView@424d2618
09-06 05:17:24.295: D/s(25590):  s>>>>>Male
09-06 05:17:24.295: D/sexxx(25590):  sexxx>>>>android.widget.LinearLayout@424d07f8
```

So all data are well retrieved , all what is missing is setting them in the `imageView`

this is User.xml :

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sex"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-67dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I am using `LayoutInflator` to get the `ImageView` and the code below is in `mailActivity.java`

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.user, cursor, from, to)

    {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_SEX"));
            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View sexxx = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user, null);
                sexlogo = (ImageView) sexxx.findViewById(R.id.sex);

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Male"))
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);

            else 
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);
            return row;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Don't inflate `R.layout.user` in `getView()`. The `super` call is already inflating it. Just use `row.findViewById()` to get the ImageView.

Comment: @MikeM. exactly , i will add the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct answer , just remove `LayoutInflater` since the `super` already inflates it .

inflating a `layout` will return a new `root`representing the `xml`

```
{

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_SEX"));
            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            sexlogo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sex);

            if (s.equals("Male"))
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);

            else
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);

            return row;

        }
    };
```